# How can I add a bottom margin using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having difficulty understanding what to do in this scenario. I am just getting acquainted with flexbox, and I see that it stretched the children to fit the height of the parent flexbox element.  I'm just trying to build some simple components without relying on bootstrap, and here I have some nested divs, with the main content being wrapped in a div with display set to flexbox, so that I can have a row of items going across like a magazine layout.  The problem is that I can't set the bottom margin, nor can I set a padding for the bottom.  Is there a way for me to use flexbox items and still maintain control of the space between the typography and the border of the outermost div?   In the code below, I am specifically referring to the div with ID='mainContentBox".  I want to include a space of about 25px between that and the div border.  Thanks for your patience.  I am just starting to wrap my mind around flexbox.  Thanks for taking the time to help me.

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.rndImg {
  width: 120px;
  height: 132px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  shape-outside: circle();
  margin-top: 24px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 75%;
}

#featured {
  position: relative;
  width: 85px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  top: 12px;
}

#titleBP_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 40%;
}

#pDate {
  position: relative;
  left: 77%;
  top: 15px;
}

#postOnStrip {
  display: inline;
}

#inOne {
  width: 500px;
}

#inTwo {
  width: 500px;
  display: inline;
}

.blogTxt {
  width: 480px;
  font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
  /*   'Roboto', sans-serif;   */
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: .8em !important;
  letter-spacing: .13em;
  text-align: justify !important;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline;
}

#topBlogReveal {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 345px;
}

#mainContentBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#marg {
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#titleStrip {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: Lavender;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#postBox {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 97%;
  height: 450px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #CCC;
}

#colorEdge1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: black;
  width: 95%;
  height: 475px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  z-index: -5;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#topBanner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.dCap {
  float: left;
  line-height: 90%;
  width: 1.1em;
  font-size: 600%;
  font-family: georgia;
}
```

```html
<div id="postBox">
  <div id="titleStrip"><a href="#" id="featured" class="btn-sm btn-primary">Featured</a>
    <h3 id="titleBP_1">Blog Post #1</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="postOnStrip">
    <p id="pDate"><b>Posted On: </b><em>June 23, 2021</em></p>
    <hr class="divider">
  </div>

  <div id="mainContentBox">
    <div id="inOne">
      <img id="topBgImg" class="rndImg" src="Images/473a9b83088edfa35bdba1b7691056ad.jpg">

      <p class="blogTxt"><span class="dCap">W</span>hat if the opiate epidemic runs deeper than purple bruises and scabrous veins running yup and down the arms of our nation's heroine addicts? What if it isn't just a socio economic problem, nor the result of international
        anatagonisms vis a vis the black marget drug trade, but rather the first symptoms of a looming existential crisis for humanity at large. The cancer patient swallows pills to ease the aching malignancy bloomin down there in the organs and tissues,
        the mess of physicality from which our consciousness is supposed to arise out of. But someti,es, the cancer patient blajets hersel fin morphine just to kill that deeper ache which starts when one percieves the horizon of their own impending demnise.
        And who can blame them Life is hard.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="inTwo">
      <p class="blogTxt">What if the opiate epidemic runs deeper than purple bruises and scabrous veins running yup and down the arms of our nation's heroine addicts? What if it isn't just a socio economic problem, nor the result of international anatagonisms vis a vis
        the black marget drug trade, but rather the first symptoms of a looming existential crisis for humanity at large. The cancer patient swallows pills to ease the aching malignancy bloomin down there in the organs and tissues, the mess of physicality
        from which our consciousness is supposed to arise out of. But someti,es, the cancer patient blajets hersel fin morphine just to kill that deeper ache which starts when one percieves the horizon of their own impending demnise. And who can blame
        them Life is hard.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="topBlogReveal">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post your code as a snippet? it will be easier to visualize

Comment: The problem is not really clear to me, try and add flex-shrink:0 to the children, or if you want ID='mainContentBox" this to have a margin from it's div parent then just add a margin

Comment: Get a grip on your gutters with `gap`. Applies to flex and grid containers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

Comment: I basically am just trying to figure out how to add a margin to the bottom of an element which is a child of a DIV whose display is set to flex, with flex-direction set to row.  I can set the side to side margins, left and right, but not the bottom.